# CodeIgniter, variable declaration

Tags: codeigniter, variables, undefined

I have a problem with undefined variable. In `view/somefolder/somefile.php` they echo some variabla (`<?php echo $news;?>` ) . I tried everything to find where this variable is defined (Find in Path at PHPStorm), but without result. When I put `print_r($GLOBALS)` to test, I got

```
[_ci_cached_vars:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [unread] => 0
                        [unans] => 0
                        [ques_unread] => 0
                        [is_loged] => 
                        [level] => 
                        [avatar] => media/img/avatar.png
                        [username] => 
                        [root_cat] => 0
                        [logErr] => 
                        [radio_list] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [entitet] => 1
                        [current_modul] => infograda
                        [tree] => <ul></ul>
                        [category] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 153
                                [title] => HRONIKA
                                [description] => 
                                [parent_id] => 0
                                [order] => 52
                                [module] => infograda
                                [expanded] => 0
                                [content_type_id] => 1
                            )

                        [module] => infograda
                        [active] => 
                        [additionHtml] => 
                        [news] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1574
                                        [content_id] => 1574
                                        [module] => infograda
                                        [order] => 
                                        [title] => Title 
                                        [text] => <div class="uvod_holder">
```

Comment: Variables in view files could be declared while loading the view inside the controller, like this: `$this->load->view("somefolder/somefile.php",array("news"=>"something"));`

Comment: +1 Look at your url. It is built like this : `index.php/controller_called/function_called`. So if you go in application/controllers/Controller_called.php you should find the view call inside function_called()

Answer (score 0):

in Codeigniter, a view is loaded from a controller. For example:

Controller:

```
// this file resides in application\controllers\mycontroller.php

class Mycontroller extends CI_Controller{
    function mypage() {
        $data = array('news' => 'some news');
        $this->load->view('page', $data);// will load views\page.php and pass the $data array
    }
}
```

View

```
<!--this file resides in application\views\page.php -->
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body><?= $news; ?></body> 
</html>
```

To make this work, your URL will say `http://localhost/index.php/mycontroller/mypage` (if you're working locally)

Your variable is being set in the controller that loads that view.

Comment: how does your URL look like?

Comment: Yea, I know thet, but there is no variable in controlor that loads this view. I search through all my application files in codeigniter...

Comment: can you edit your question and provide us with how your controller looks like?

Comment: sounds like a caching issue. Try searching Codeigniter caching variable and see what you find. I will do the same and let you know.